# How to get the elevation value of a specific location from DEM using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, dem, elevation

I am trying to understand how and if it is possible to get - extract the elevation value of a specific point (given x,y values) from a DEM layer in the GeoServer.

The only values that i am able to get back using the GetFeatureInfo is the following (example):

```
type    "FeatureCollection"
features    
0   
type    "Feature"
id  ""
geometry    null
properties  
GRAY_INDEX  -3.4028234663852886e+38
totalFeatures   "unknown"
numberReturned  1
timeStamp   "2022-06-23T10:29:05.858Z"
crs null
```

I have also check the following tutorial:
[https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_time-elevationseries.html]

But again, i think that this is not exactly applied at my case.

Comment: Make a WCS request for the data rather than a WMS request for a picture of the data

Comment: If you have a try with the demo layer http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=nurc%3Amosaic&STYLES&LAYERS=nurc%3Amosaic&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=9.201049492%2C38.51237725%2C11.420292%2C40.73181 you will get back the pixel values `98.0 114.0 81.0 255.0` for red, green, blue, and alpha. You got `GRAY_INDEX  -3.4028234663852886e+38` that feels like nodata to me. Check your GFI request.

Comment: I will check the WCS request, thanks! Regarding the demo layer, i could see only RGB values, so maybe if the raster layer has the elevation value available will be displayed along with others?

Comment: It is OK to use GetFeatureInfo for your query. The "mosaic" layer is RGBA and bad as a DEM example, sorry.  But there is also a DEM example in the demo layers. http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sf/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=sf%3Asfdem&STYLES&LAYERS=sf%3Asfdem&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A26713&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=597674.3187724616%2C4918272.770715153%2C601530.0675488889%2C4922128.519491579 return 1459.0.

Comment: You are right, but this example gives me back only the GRAY_INDEX not the actual elevation value of the point. That's my issue.

Comment: GRAY_INDEX should be what you have in your data. Is it not? Is there scaling/offset applied to your source data? What is your GeoServer version, I am remembering that old versions make GFI request to rendered image and that lead to wrong results with 16 bit source data or when DEM was colored with SLD. The sf:dem layer work OK for me with GeoServer 2.20 so that GRAY_INDEX=1371 means height in meters. About using WCS, there is related discussion in https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-coverages/issues/112.

Comment: Yes, you are right GRAY_INDEX is what i have in my data (DEM). My current version is 2.21 so, what i got back form GRAY_INDEX attribute is the height in meters? I did not now that... I will check also the discussion for the WCS request, thanks!

Comment: @user30184 you are right, i made some more tests and the GRAY_INDEX corresponds to the elevation value of the x,y point. One more related question, i am searching also of how to run GetFeatureInfo request + DEM not only for a point, but also for a bbox for example. I know that it's possible to do this using for example leaflet.js or something similar, but i would like to do it via the GeoServer, do you know if this is possible?

Comment: WMS GetFeatureInfo supports only query by point. For bbox query WCS is good even it requires some client side libraries to read the height values from a format like GeoTIFF. Depending on your use case asciigrid format could be easier to parse because it is plain text. If your aim is to get a height profile along a line then no existing OGC standard is rather handy for that. By reading smallish rectangles along the route with WCS and finding the heights at vertices of the line on the client side is doable.